# android_core - Emulator registers topic but not sending events

Tags: ros, android-core, android-gingerbread, rosjava-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got android_core and rosjava_core as projects under Android Studio.
I'm currently running a Ginerbread (API:10) emulator and debugging it.

The android_tutorial_pubsub registers it's self as a topic publisher
and I can see that the topic has been registered with roscore.

'rostopic list' sees the topic but doesn't see any events with
'rostopic echo /mychatter

```
'$ rostopic list
    /mychatter
     /rosout
    /rosout_agg 

$ rostopic echo /mychatter
```

wireshark show the http message being sent to register the /mychatter
topic but nothing thereafter. Browser on emulator shows the web page
fine on the rosecore host. The debugger shows the app is waiting to accept something.

My guess is that the 'rostopic echo /mychatter' should be connecting to the
android_tutorial_pubsub app on the emulator.

Thought while debugging id see if anyone had any suggestions.
I'll double check the wireshark trace and compare it to android_tutorial_pubsub
running in the rosjava_core running locally on my workstation.

I thought I'd try to increase the logging level on the ROS Java Related Nodes:

```
 $ rosnode list
        /android_gingerbread/ros_text_view
        /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker
        /rosout
```

So here I tried to list the loggers on the ROS Nodes. The ROS-JAVA related nodes seem to be Broken:

```
$ rosconsole list /rosout
        ros
        ros.roscpp
        ros.roscpp.roscpp_internal
        ros.roscpp.superdebug

$ rosconsole list /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker
        rosconsole: error: node '/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker' doesn't exist ...
        or doesn't support query: ...
        Service [/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker/get_loggers] is not available.

$ rosconsole list  /android_gingerbread/ros_text_view
        rosconsole: error: node '/android_gingerbread/ros_text_view' doesn't exist or ...
        doesn't support query: ...
        Service    [/android_gingerbread/ros_text_view/get_loggers] is not available.
```

-pete

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223602/android_core---emulator-registers-topic-but-not-sending-events/) by [piet.delaney@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/25493/piet.delaney@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-01-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-07**:
Many issues like this with the Android emulator come down to incorrect networking configuration. Things to check: working DNS on both host and emulator (if you're using hostnames), correct setting of `ROS_IP` (if not using hostnames), firewall/NAT settings (prefer bridging), etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-07**:
Can you update your question and include the values of `ROS_MASTER_URI`, `ROS_HOSTNAME`, `ROS_IP` and the network configuration of both your host PC and the emulated Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**FIXED IT:****strong text**

I analysed the problem with WireShark this afternoon. The problem was that the Android Emulator (QEMU)
has a built in firewall, thus using masquerading. The pubsub publisher sends the local ip address running on the
emulated cell phone and the emulated firewall changes the address at host side, likely with a bridge. So the
ROS Core running on a Ubuntu system was taking fine with HTTP thru the firewall but when I did a:

```
                                   'rostopic echo \mychatter'
```

it was trying to send a direct TCP/IP connection directly to the host address inside the emulator. So the SYN
packets were just being lost.

**I installed pubsub on an Nexus Tablet, not an emulation, and it worked fine.** Seems worthy of
a **NOTE** in the Android_Core Tutorial that ***This demo  doesn't work on a Emulated android device the currently described setup with Android Studio ***. I mentioned
it in my Question/Description that this was an Android Emulation. I don't know of anything I could have done on
Android Studio to get around this. If there is it surely is worth mentioning in the Wiki pages in **BOLD.**

Anyone know if there is anything set up in ROS to avoid this problem in the Studio setup? Seems pretty silly for ROS
to be limited to only machines behind the same firewall. Did I miss something in the tutorial? I was wondering if ROS_IP is provided with ROS_MASTER_URI for non Android Studion emulations to allow ROS to operate thru firewalls. I've picked up a few books on ROS and so far haven't read anyting about special proceedures to take for firewalls.

I just looked on the web and find this:

```
  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

          What about firewalls?
                 If there is a firewall, or other obstruction, between a pair of machines 
                 that you want to use with ROS, you need to create a virtual network
                 to connect them. 

                 We recommend openvpn.
```

This seems like a rather awkward limitation. Like hooking up some language recognition software in a clowd like Amazon AWS to control robots runing ROS.

-piet

---

Originally posted by [piet.delaney@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/25493/piet.delaney@gmail.com/) with karma: 56 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-09**:
NAT-traversal (or punching) is indeed not something that is dealt with by the middleware (natively), but is considered a system configuration issue. Hence the recommendation to solve this using non-ROS tools. There are more middlewares requiring extra configuration to work across NAT or through fws.

**Comment by [breandan](https://answers.ros.org/users/32982/breandan/) on 2019-03-19**:
I also encountered this issue, and have been unable to resolve it. Yes - it works on a physical device, but is there any way to run the emulator headlessly for UI testing in the Android emulator with ROS on Docker? I would like to bypass or disable the QEMU firewall, but was unable to find any documentation about this.